# Redux - Loading indicator while waiting for promise

Tags: promise, redux

I have a simple redux application that is displaying articles by requesting data from an api. I want to display "loading" indicator while waiting for promise. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two parties are involved: store and component representation.

In store, per reducer, you should add a prop and call it, say, `loading`. So the reducer's initial state would look like

```
// src/reducers/whatevs.js
const initialState = {
  // whatever
  loading: false
};
```

Then, pass this value into container's props with `connect` function, like

```
export default connect(({whatevs}) => ({
  // props you want to use in this container, and
  loading: whatevs.loading
}));
```

Next, you want to call an action and retrieve a Promise from it, so it's simply

```
componentWillMount() {
  const promise = requestSomething();

  this.props.dispatch(() => {
    type: LOADING_SOMETHING
  });
  promise.then((smth) => this.props.dispatch(() => {
    type: LOADED_SOMETHING,
    ...smth
  }));
}
```

So, first, you claim that you requested something, therefore you're loading; then, you claim that the response has been received, so you're not loading anymore. The corresponding reducers would look like

```
LOADING_SOMETHING: (state) => ({
  ...state,
  loading: true
})
```

and

```
LOADED_SOMETHING: (state, {type, ...smth}) => ({
  ...state,
  ...smth,
  loading: false
})
```

And in the component, simply rely on `loading` prop to make it render either loading indicator or actual data:

```
render() {
  const {loading} = this.props;

  if (loading) {
    return (
      <LoadingIndicator />
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <WhateverComponent />
    );
  }
}
```

### Connect function

The `connect` function from react-redux package wraps a component and allows it to receive props from the application state aka the Store on every Provider component update. It happens reactively, which means top to bottom, every time you dispatch an action. A store is typically a plain-object (or may it be Immutable.js's Map object, or anything) that, conventionally, contains as many properties as you have reducers.

You can check the value of application state using React DevTools. Just open them, highlight the Provider component, and type

```
$r.props.store.getState()
```

You wrap every controlled component (may be called container, or view) with `connect` function to make it receive every update of the state and re-render if a part of the app state the component depends on changes.

For example, let's pretend the app state is

```
{
  authentication: {
    authenticated: null,
    username: null
  },
  photos: {
    items: [],
    favorites: []
  }
}
```

and you have a component

```
export default class Photos extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      photoList
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>{this.renderPhotoList(photoList)}</div>
    );
  }
}
```

And what you really want is that `photoList` prop of this component would refer to `photos.items` property of the app state. Then you connect app state's `photos.items` property to component's `photoList` prop:

```
class Photos extends Component {
  render() {
    const {
      photoList
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>{doSomethingMeaningful(photoList)}</div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect((state) => ({
  photoList: state.photos.items // remember $r.props.store.getState()?
}))(Photos);
```

or, with some destructuring assignment,

```
export default connect(({photos}) => ({
  photoList: photos.items
}))(Photos);
```

The `connect` function accepts either one or two arguments, in this particular example there's only one argument that binds component's props to app state's properties.

There could be the second parameter, which is a function of dispatch:

```
import {
  fetchPhotos
} from 'actions/photos';

export default connect(({photos}) => ({
  photoList: photos.items
}), {
  fetchPhotos
})(Photos);
```

Which is a different topic.

Need some deeper explanation of how `connect` works? [See the ref](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments).

Comment: Edits and comments are very welcome. I was short in time so I could make some mistakes or simply be unclear at some points.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit late on this, but I'm trying to do the same thing. I didn't understand what's supposed to be in the connect() function, especially because I'm used to see it with a mapStateToProps and actions as arguments, not with a function... Could you please clarify this part?

Comment: Good question, I'll update the answer in a few days, please be patient. :)

Comment: Thanks! I look forward to this!

Comment: Just expanded the answer, however, honestly, I'd strongly recommend you to dedicate an hour of your time and read thoroughly through the [official documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#arguments) and see what each argument means and what are default values of each.

Comment: Thanks! Actually I understood it just before you answered, but I'm sure this is going to be helpful to others!